# Increment counter : Xpath

Tags: variables, xpath

I am looking for a solution to address my issue described below,

I wanted to increment variable from 0 to 'n' using Xpath so that i can use the incremented variable. 'n' is the count of an element.

So assuming n = 3 ,i would like to get values like 0,1,2 as output.

```
I
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <r> 
      <intro>
        <longtitle> Demo </longtitle>
      </intro>
       .....<BIG JUNK>
      <intro>
        <longtitle> Test </longtitle>
      </intro>  
       .....<BIG JUNK>
      <intro>
        <longtitle>Demo Test</longtitle>
      </intro> 
      .....<BIG JUNK>
    </r>
```

so here when the first index of "intro/longtitle" is encountered i wanted the counter to initilize and show "0" . When second index is encountered "1" to be displayed.and so on

Sriram

Comment: Do you need to use the incremented number in the xpath and to retrieve the value from the same?

Comment: Yes, if the first output is 0 , i will this 0 to be shown in  my pDF and then would need the 0 to get incrementede to 1.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML of the page, so that I can help you